# Cambiar de ViewController en código Swift Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

quiero compartirles un problema que no he podido solucionar, así que les pido de sus conocimientos para que me ayuden porfavor.

He creado una pantalla walkthrough el cual desplaza un slide de imagen e información con el boton next y skip para saltar a otra pantalla.
En el ultimo slide programe el boton next a get started y este cumplira la función de saltar tambien a otra pantalla, sin embargo, no hallo la formula para hacer dicho cambio en el codigo, así que les comparto lo que tengo y espero sus comentarios.

Para comenzar cree un file swift con el siguiente atributo:

```
import Foundation
struct Konstants {
struct Storyboard {
   static let homesViewController = "HomesViewController"
    static let signUpViewController = "SignViewController"
}}
```

donde dice SignviewController fue para hacer algo similar y en este caso si me funciono, por lo que creo que el error debe estar en la ubicación del codigo en el file del walkthrough, el cual, es el siguiente...

```
 @IBAction func nextButtonTapped(sender:UIButton) {
if let index = walkthroughViewController?.currentIndex {
switch index {
case 0...1:
walkthroughViewController?.forwardPage()
            
case 2 :

    // SKIP 
    
    func transitionToSignUp() {
    let signUpViewController =
        
    storyboard?.instantiateViewController (identifier: Konstants.Storyboard.signUpViewController) as?
        SignViewController
        
        view.window?.rootViewController = signUpViewController
        view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        
    }
    
dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
default: break
}
}
    
updateUI()
    
}

func updateUI() {
    if let index = walkthroughViewController?.currentIndex {
        switch index {
        case 0...1:
            nextButton.setTitle("Next", for: .normal)
            skipButton.isHidden = false
            iconskip1.isHidden = false
            iconskip2.isHidden = false
            
        case 2:
            nextButton.setTitle("Get Started", for: .normal)
            skipButton.isHidden = true
            iconskip1.isHidden = true
            iconskip2.isHidden = true
            
        default: break
        }
        
        pageControl.currentPage = index
    }
}

func didUpdatePageIndex(currentIndex: Int) {
    updateUI()
}
```

todo funciona bien menos donde coloque el mensaje //SKIP Para cambiar de pantalla, porfavor necesito de la ayuda de gente con estos conocimientos. Muchas gracias.

Comment: En dónde llamas a esta función `transitionToSignUp()`? Intentaste solo con el código del `case` quitando la función?

Comment: Lo probare amigo y te comento, gracias por tu aporte.

Answer (score 0):

Veo que en el case 2 no haces ninguna llamada, hasta donde puedo entender, veo que quieres llamar a la funcion `transitionToSignUp()` pero jamas podras hacer la llamada porque nunca la usas.

intenta poner la funcion `transitionToSignUp()` afuera del button y luego haces la llamada de tu funcion dentro del case 2

Comment: Gracias mi amigo por tu aporte, afortunadamente probe la opción del otro compañero y me funciono. Sin embargo, voy a probar tu metodo ya que también me interesa saber todos los campos que maneja la plataforma, muchas gracias.

Comment: Para mejorar tu codigo, puedes usar los principios SOLID, te va a ayudar a tener un mejor orden y una mejor estructura 